# AlignParentBottom button overlaps Textview on Scroll/Focus

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

Currently, I have a few Android xml layouts with multiple Textviews that data can be entered into. At the bottom of the relative layout is a button with the attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` with the text "Save Changes", which is expected to display above the keyboard, when the keyboard pops up.

However, when clicking on a textview towards the bottom of the list, once focused, the "Save Changes" button is overlapping with the focused Textview.

**Note:** it IS possible to manually scroll down a bit more yourself, to then see the Textview.

[image]

Ideally the functionality here would be to adjust the scrollTo() to effectively scroll to the focused element and place it into view just above the "Save Changes" button.

I've tried setting this value in the activitys attributes in the manifest:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Along with wrapping the Relative Layout in a LinearLayout, or adding padding to the bottom of the ScrollView to no avail.

Here's my current XML excluding the Title bar:

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/edit_info_section"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_below="@id/activity_title_border_bottom">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/edit_info_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/huge_padding"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/huge_padding">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_firstname_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/label_firstname"
        style="@style/label_text"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/account_firstname_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        style="@style/EditTextStyle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_lastname_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/label_lastname"
        style="@style/label_text"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/account_lastname_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        style="@style/EditTextStyle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_phone_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/label_phone"
        style="@style/label_text"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/account_phone_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLines="1"
        style="@style/EditTextStyle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_email_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/label_email"
        style="@style/label_text"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/account_email_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        style="@style/EditTextStyle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_password_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/label_password"
        style="@style/label_text"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/account_password_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        style="@style/EditTextStyle" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save_changes"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/save_changes"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    style="style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What would be the best way to scroll to the focused textview, while still showing the "Save changes" button above the keyboard?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your layout is approximately:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView>
        ...
    </ScrollView>

    <Button/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem with this structure is that the `ScrollView` fills the whole screen. In other words, a portion of the `ScrollView` is *always* "behind" the `Button`... it's just only problematic when the keyboard comes up.

Instead, I think you should use this layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ...>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ...>

        ...

    </ScrollView>

    <Button/>

</LinearLayout>
```

By doing this, you make sure that it's impossible to have content in your `ScrollView` go behind your button, but you still get the `Button` pushed all the way to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks Ben, this appears to be mostly working. However there appears to be some white space/padding displaying above the "Save Changes" button, which is still overlapping with the Scrollview and its not too apparent where this is coming from, as removing padding from the button does not fix the issue. https://i.imgur.com/gCeolO4.png

Comment: @Alkarin If you replace the `<Button>` with just a `<View>` (something really simple with no margins/padding) does it still happen?

Comment: Think I found the culprit. Removing `android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"` from the `<Scrollview>` fixed it, which i'm not sure why. Also could you maybe update your answer as to WHY setting the orientation to vertical/setting scrollview height to 0dp works? Other thank that, thanks a lot! I will accept your answer.